# How can I remove a module if it is already imported in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, module

I am adding some modules dynamically in my script at the start-up.

I want to remove a module if it is already imported just before importing it.

How can I remove module Foo if it is already imported in Powershell?

Answer (score 2):

you can also use import-module Foo -force, if you want to 'reload' it

Comment: yeah rather use force than try remove and re import

Answer (score 0):

Same as answer before:

```
 get-module Foo | remove-module
```

or

```
remove-module foo -ea silentlycontinue
```